# Текст не движется с полосой прокрутки

Tags: python, tkinter

Текст не движется с полосой прокрутки как будто текст не привязан к ней. В всплывающем окне видна середина текста, а не начало и полоса прокрутки движется, а текст стоит на месте. Никак не могу разобраться с полосой прокрутки.

```
def window_open(label_1):  # Всплывающее окно
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title("Химические элементы таблицы Менделеева")
    toplevel.geometry("500x500+600+200")

    label_new = Label(toplevel, text=label_1, height=0, width=100, 
                       wraplength=500)
    label_1 = Text(toplevel)

    scroll = Scrollbar(toplevel, orient='vertical')
    label_1.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll['command'] = label_1.yview

    label_1.pack
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    label_new.pack()
```

1. Как сделать чтобы текст открывался с начала, а не с середины?
2. Как полосу прокрутки привязать к тексту?
3. Где можно почитать про Scrollbar?

Comment: а какой текст по вашему мнению должен скролиться? тот который вы печатаете в `Label` или тот в котором вы сами вводите данные `Text`? потому что вы добавляете какие то данные в `Label` а скролите данные в `Text`

Comment: Нужно скролить данные 'label_1' , не пойму как это сделать

Comment: Label не поддерживает прокрутку. Но можно поместить ее внутрь Canvas - он поддерживает.

Comment: @insolor как бы это не было странно, но `label_1` у него `Text` )

Comment: @Twiss, действительно, не обратил внимание)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас сам `label_1` не отображается в `Toplevel` вы забыли дописать скобки функции `pack()`
немного исправил ваш код для более корректности :)

Про `ScrollBar` можно прочитать [тута](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm)

```
from tkinter import *


def window_open(label_1):  # Всплывающее окно
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title("Химические элементы таблицы Менделеева")
    toplevel.geometry("500x500+600+200")

    label = Label(toplevel, text="Какой то текст", height=0, width=100, wraplength=500)
    label.pack()
    scroll = Scrollbar(toplevel, orient='vertical')
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    text = Text(toplevel)
    text.insert(END, label_1 * 5)
    text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)


a = """def window_open(label_1):  # Всплывающее окно
    toplevel = Toplevel()
    toplevel.title("Химические элементы таблицы Менделеева")
    toplevel.geometry("500x500+600+200")

    label_new = Label(toplevel, text=label_1, height=0, width=100, 
                       wraplength=500)
    label_1 = Text(toplevel)

    scroll = Scrollbar(toplevel, orient='vertical')
    label_1.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    scroll['command'] = label_1.yview

    label_1.pack
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    label_new.pack()

"""
root = Tk()
but = Button(root, text="Нажми", command=lambda: window_open(a))
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Я сам не разобрался до сих пор, сейчас буду в свою программу добавлять. Это моя первая программа. [https://github.com/maxim58r/Chemistry/commits/master] 
 вот ссылка на саму программу, еще правда скролл не заработал